# Finding all the ordered pairs of integers lying on a line ax+by=c in better than O(n^2) time complexity

Tags: c++, linear-equation

I am trying to write a code which can input 3 long int variables, a, b, c.
The code should find all integer (x,y) so that ax+by = c, but the input values can be up to 2*10^9. I'm not sure how to do this efficiently. My algorithm is O(n^2), which is really bad for such large inputs. How can I do it better? Here's my code-

```
typedef long int lint;

struct point
{
lint x, y;
};

int main()
{
lint a, b, c;
vector <point> points;
cin >> c >> a >> b;
for(lint x = 0; x < c; x++)
    for(lint y = 0; y < c; y++)
    {
        point candidate;
        if(a*x + b*y == c)
        {
            candidate.x = x;
            candidate.y = y;
            points.push_back(candidate);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't `x` and `y` be negative ?

Comment: You should check the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), which is the fastest algorithm (as far as I know) to solve this diophantine equations.

Comment: Your code ASSUMES that `c` is positive, and only checks non-negative values of `x` and `y`.    Under the same constraints, it would be trivial to eliminate the inner loop and detect if there are ANY values.   Then a simpler loop, if there is one value, to find the others.  Without those constraints, the number of potential pairs is infinite.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the post, a, b, and c must be positive values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can apply a tiny bit of really trivial math to solve for `y` for any given value of `x`. Starting from `ax + by = c`:

```
ax + by = c

by = c - ax
```

Assuming non-zero `b`<sup>1</sup>, we then get:

```
y = (c - ax) / b
```

With that in hand, we can generate our values of `x` in the loop, plug it into the equation above, and compute the matching value of `y` and check whether it's an integer. If so, add that (x, y) pair, and go on to the next value of `x`.

You could, of course, make the next step and figure out which values of `x` would result in the required `y` being an integer, *but* even without doing that we've moved from O(N<sup>2</sup>) to O(N), which is likely to be plenty to get the task done in a much more reasonable time frame.

---

1. Of course, if `b` is 0, then the `by` term is zero, so we have `ax = c`, which we can then turn into `x = c/a`, so we then just need to check that `x` is an integer, and if so all pairs of that `x` with any candidate value of `y` will yield the correct `c`.